# Gedmo Loggable doesn't log in his table "ext_log_entries"

Tags: symfony, logging, gedmo-loggable

I'm trying to use Gedmo\Loggable to log any changes for an entity.
This is my implementation :

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class MyClass
{
```

On the field

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 */
private $type;
```

In my doctrine.yaml :

```
                gedmo_loggable:
                    type: annotation
                    prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                    alias: GedmoLoggable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                    is_bundle: false
```

When I update the field for this entity. No logs are inserted in the Gedmo's table "ext_log_entries", am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Versioned
 * @ORM\Column(length=8)
 */
private $type;
```

I forgot about `@ORM\Column(length=8)`